# Create PowerShell script to send an email if files are older than 30 minutes

Tags: powershell, scripting

I need to run a script against automatically created and purged files in a directory.

I used the script from here:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/Powershell/Q_26895555.html

The problem with this script is it sends the email regardless of whether it finds any offending files or not.

Also it detects the old file and sends an email but when it's time to check again it doesn't report the file again.

I would like to run this as a scheduled task (which I know how to do) but I want it to only send the email if it finds offending files and I want it to report the offenders every time it checks.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The single-line answer would look something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test | Where-Object -FilterScript { ([DateTime]::Now - $_.LastWriteTime).TotalMinutes -ge 30; } | ForEach-Object -Begin { $FileList = @(); } -Process { $FileList += $_.Name; } -End { Send-MailMessage -Body $FileList ... ... ... ...; };
```

In the `-End` `ScriptBlock` of the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, you can call the `Send-MailMessage` command, and pass in the `$FileList` variable, which gets built during the `-Process` `ScriptBlock` of the `ForEach-Object`. Overall, this is turning into a fairly lengthy single-line command though, so we can break it down to make it more understandable, and define a nice, prettier message body for the e-mail.

Here is a longer answer, that breaks it down into pieces:

```
$FileNameList = @();
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test;

foreach ($File in $FileList) {
   if (([DateTime]::UtcNow - $File.LastWriteTimeUtc).TotalMinutes -ge 30) {
        $FileNameList += $File.Name;
    }
}

$MessageBody = @"
The following files were older than 30 minutes:

{0}
"@ -f ($FileNameList -join "`n");

Send-MailMessage -Body $MessageBody ... ... ... ...;
```

Comment: Never mind about the first question but does this halt if it does not find any files older than 30 minutes or does it still send a blank email?

Comment: It will still send a blank e-mail. I understand your question to be asking specifically for this behavior, however it could easily be modified to halt.

Comment: In the latter example, you can make it halt by using this code: `if ($FileNameList.Count -eq 0) { return; }`

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a try

Comment: I must have the syntax wrong somewhere, can you give me a complete example script? I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Which example are you using? The short one or the long one? I didn't completely fill out the `Send-MailMessage` parameters. You'll have to complete those parameter values for your own environment, such as: `-To`, `-From`, `-Subject`, etc.